# SUMIFS with intermediate VLOOKUP in the criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have 3 tables, 1 of which I want to fill in columns with data based on the other 2. Tables are roughly structured as follows:

```
Table 1 (Semi-Static Data)

SubGroup        Group
-----------     -----------
subgroup(1)     group(a)
subgroup(2)     group(b)
subgroup(3)     group(b)
subgroup(4)     group(c)
etc.

Table 2 (Variable Data)

SubGroup        DataValue
-----------     -----------
subgroup(1)     datavalue(i)
subgroup(2)     datavalue(ii)
subgroup(3)     datavalue(iii)
subgroup(4)     datavalue(iv)
etc.

Table 3 (Results)

Group           TotalValue
-----------     -----------
group(a)        totalvalue(m)
group(b)        totalvalue(n)
group(c)        totalvalue(o)
etc.
```

Where the TotalValue is the sum of all DataValue's for all subgroups that belong to that particular Group.

e.g. for group(b) --->  totalvalue(n) = datavalue(ii) + datavalue(iii)

I am looking to achieve this calculation without adding any additional columns to the Data tables nor using VBA.

Basically I need to perform a COUNTIFS where there is an additional VLOOKUP matching the subgroup criteria range to the group it belongs to, and then only summing for datavalue's that match the group being evaluated. I have tried using array formulas but I'm having issues making it work. Any assistance would be very appreciated. Thank you,

EDIT: Wanted to add some details surrounding my question. First all Google searches did not provide a suitable answer. All the links had solutions to a slightly different problem were the VLOOKUP term is not dependent on the SUMIFS criteria but rather another single static variable. Stack Overflow offered similar solutions. Please let me know if anymore details are required to make my post suitable for this forum. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SUMPRODUCT function to do it all at once.  The first reference $B$2:$B$5 is for the Group names, the second reference $E$2:$E$5 is for the datavalues.  The G2 reference is for the group names in the third table, you can enter this formula for the first reference and then drag and fill for the rest.

> =SUMPRODUCT($E$2:$E$5 * (G2 = $B$2:$B$5))

Comment: Thank you for your answer Lance. I think this would not be applicable, mostly as it seems my examples were not very helpful. Table1 and Table2 do not have the same dimensions and the subgroups in are not ordered the same (unlike my example). So G2 = $B$2:$B$5 would not produce an array that you could multiply by the DataValues. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding your solution and my apologies for the ambiguous example.

Comment: No, you're right, my solution was based on your example showing the first two tables both just listing every subgroup, so that the number of rows in each would be the same.  The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Some cell references, and sample data, would be helpful but something like this might be what you want:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,"="&INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E5,B:B,0)),D:D)
```

Answer (score 0):

WADR & IMHO, this is simply bad worksheet design. For lack of a single cross-reference column in **Table2**, any solution would have to be a VBA *User Defined Formula* or an overly complicated array formula (the latter of which I am not even sure is possible). The data tables are not normalized database tables you can `INNER JOIN` or `GROUP BY ... HAVING`.

The formula you are trying to achieve is akin to,

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(D:D, {"subgroup(2)","subgroup(3)"}, E:E))`

That only works with hard-coded values as *arrayed constants* (e.g. `{"subgroup(2)","subgroup(3)"}`). I know of no way to spit a dynamic list back into the formula using additional native Excel functions but VBA offers some possibilities.

**HOWEVER,**

The simple addition of one more column to **Table2** with a very basic `VLOOKUP` reduces all of your problems to a `SUMIF`.

[image: Solution to Overly complicated]

The formula in the new column D, row 2 is,

`=VLOOKUP(E2, A:B, 2, FALSE)`

The formula in I2 is,

`=SUMIF(D:D, H2,F:F )`

Fill  each down as necessary. Sorry if that is not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: I appreciate your honest answer. I have gotten to a point where I think it is possible to achieve this with array formulas. I created a formula that outputs an array representing all subgroups in a given group:

{=IFERROR(INDEX([Table1.xlsx]Sheet1!SubGroup,SMALL(IF([Table1.xlsx]Sheet1!Group=G2,ROW([Table1.xlsx]Sheet1!SubGroup)-1),ROWS([Table1.xlsx]Sheet1!SubGroup))),"")}

I am now left with using this array to do a conditional sum for all items that are contained in this array but I am not able to progress further than that. Any further help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone that responded and reviewed this post. I have managed to resolve this using an array formula and some matrix algebra. Please note that I am not using VLOOKUP (this operator cannot be performed on arrays) nor SUMIFS as my title states.

My final formula looks like this:

```
{=SUM(IF([Table2.xlsx]Sheet1!SubGroup=TRANSPOSE(IF([Table1.xlsx]Sheet1!Group=G2,[Table1.xlsx]Sheet1!SubGroup,"")),[Table2.xlsx]Sheet1!DataValue))}
```

Very simply, I create an array variable that compares the Group being evaluated (e.g. cell G2) with the Groups column for Table 1 and outputs the corresponding matching SubGroups. This results in an array with as many rows as Table 1 had (N) and 1 column: Nx1. I then transpose that array (1xN) and compare it to the SubGroups column (Mx1, M being the number of rows in Table 2) and output the DataValues column for the rows that have a corresponding SubGroup (MxN). Then I perform a sum of the whole array to return a single value.

Notice that as I didn't include a value_if_false output return on either IF operators, it will just populate with FALSE in the arrays were the conditions are not met. This does not matter though for the final result. In the first IF, FALSE will not match the SubGroups so will be ignored. For the second all values FALSE passed to SUM will be calculated as 0. The more complicated question is that it grows the amount of memory required to process as we are not filtering to just have the values we want.

For this application I decided against filtering the subarray as the trade-off in resource utilization was acceptable. If the data sets were any bigger though, I would definitely try doing it. Another concern was that I did not understand fully the filtering logic that I was using based on http://exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/ so decided to simplify. Will revisit this concept latter as I think it will work. I might have completed this solution but was missing transposing the array to compare properly so abandoned this route.